# Adding dependencies in package.json of an express project

Tags: json, node.js, express, dependencies

Assume the following scenario. Suppose I am developing an express project named `test`. In that project I am using a node module named `x`. `x` uses another module named `y`. I have already added `x` to the dependencies of `package.json` of project `test`. Do I need to add `y` too? Simple intuition says I don't need to but it's causing me problem. Any help?

Comment: Can you describe what problems you encounter?

Comment: @Ruel, In my case `y` is `mysql`. When I run the project `test` it is giving me error saying that it can't find `mysql` module.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes you need to add `y`. From what I understand, it works the other way around. If you have `y` already installed as your projects dependency, `x` won't need to install it as its dependency.

Node looks at the upper level directories (before looking at the current directory) if there are present `node_modules` folders, and searches them if the module you are looking for is already present.